# is it possible to get data like Heart rate , calories etc from Nordic UART service?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am wandering to know how to get blood pressure, calories burnt, cycling etc. data from a band which has Nordic UART service. Please help me out i didn't find any relevant answers anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, why not. It depends how data is encoded in order to receive good values. You can check [this repository](https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-nRF-Toolbox) for examples or you can search other on Google.